# How to generate barcode using textfield value iphone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am able to read bar code using `AVCaptureDevice`, `AVCaptureDeviceInput`, `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` in iOS 7.

I need to generate barcode from input numbers in a text field.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success with this [ZXing Objective C Port](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC)